# Nginx Location based try files?

Tags: nginx, centos

I was reading this page here https://help.sorryapp.com/en/articles/2783542-install-maintenance-pages-on-nginx that had a nifty idea of having a file present means nginx would route to a maintenance html page.

But then reading through the nginx docs it seems like if statements within the location block are not ideal, and instead to use try files. Whats the proper way to rewrite whats in the above to how nginx would like it? https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

I assume is something like: but what about a rewrite?

```
try_files /my/file/path/maint.on
error_page 503 @maintenance_page;
location @maintenance_page {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance_page.html break;
```

?

### UPDATE 1

this is my current config snippit, which happens to for some reason result in a 404 even through the maint.on file doesn't exist.

```
      location / {
         if (-f /opt/staytus/staytus/maint.on) {
            return 503;
        }
        port_in_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://example.com:8787/;
        }

 error_page 503 @Performing-Maintenance;

    location @Performing-Maintenance {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ Performing-Maintenance.html break;
    }
}
```

any thought on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As the same article states,

> The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are:
>
> - `return ...;`
> - `rewrite ... last;`

so the example you're found can be considered completely safe. (I'd say it is safe to use any directive from [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) inside the `if` block which extends this list to `break`, `return`, `rewrite` and `set`). You can't do what you want with the `try_files` directive because it is requires at least one *file* argument before the last *uri* (or the name of named location or HTTP error code) argument which would be used if none of the files/directories from the list are actually exists. Well, I could imagine something like

```
location / {
    try_files /maintenance.html @default;
}

location @default {
    ...
}
```

but you can't make it serving some location like

```
location = /maintenance.html {
    ...
}
```

, it would just return the contents of `maintenance.html` file. And if `maintenance.html` page would refer to some additional assets (like CSS, JS etc.) all user browser requests for that assets would lead to the `maintenance.html` contents (because that file exists and passed the `try_files` check). Just FYI, this directive

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.php =404;
}
...
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

won't serve the `$uri/index.php` file through the PHP location handler (it just return its raw content), while this

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

would.

However example you provided would have some performance impact (especially on the high-load servers) due to the extra `stat` kernel call made for every incoming request. I'd recommend [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1022745/nginx-maintenance-mode-configuration/1022748#1022748) method of enabling maintenance mode with nginx.

Comment: hmm but your linked option has me editing the nginx/sites-enabled conf every time for maintenance mode?